# Java Swing - CardLayout, how to 'update' cards while running?

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I am pretty new at . **Java Swing**, and am using the **CardLayout** for my application. In this app a user can create activities and, in an other JPanel, view the existing ones.

I am having trouble updating the card (where the label is in). If I add the activity, when you restart the app it works fine. I am looking for a way that doesn't require restarting.

So in short, I would like to know how I should best reconstruct/update a panel whilst running so that the new label data is shown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you adding activity in EventDispatchThread SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)?

Comment: No, I actually haven't implemented any way to update, and I don't know your method..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add a component to a visible GUI you need to tell the GUI that a component has been added so the layout manager can be invoked:

```
panel.add( component );
panel.revalidate();
```

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem!! thanks XD I've been struggling ages with this

Comment: i have one panel which insert employee info. and another panel which display employee listing.which of both are in card layout. after inserting new employee and show next panel for employee listing but employee listing not refresing. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the Observer design pattern.

Basicly what it's all about is you have one Observer instance, which you add all your panels to. When you update a value in a panel, you nofity the Observer something's changed. The Observer will then inform all his observed panels that a value has changed, and they'll update their value.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern